# How to find the definition of a function or a class name using grep or find?

Tags: c, linux, bash, mono, grep

I am new to Linux development and I have to work with Mono project on Linux. I have the following function declaration:

```
static MonoString *ves_icall_System_MonoType_getFullName (MonoReflectionType *object, gboolean full_name,
                                   gboolean assembly_qualified)

{
    MonoDomain *domain = mono_object_domain (object);
    ...
```

I would like to find the definition of `MonoReflectionType` and the implementation of function `mono_object_domain`. How do I use grep and find to do this with two separate bash commands? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not a quick grep, but you could look at running [doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) on your source. You'll get cross-linked HTML references with the right options, which is pretty handy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grep and find can do it but I think they're no the best tool for it. You'd be better off using ctags: http://ctags.sourceforge.net/.

Do this from the top level directory of your project:

```
$ ctags -R *
$ vi -t MonoReflectionType
```

I hope you're familiar with vi though ;)

Answer (score 3):

You should probably be using **[CTags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags)** because that is more easier.

I hope your purpose is to find the definition while examining code and analyzing, with CTags you will find it very easy.